# Where is the left packages store location?

Tags: android

under my directory `/Users/dele/software/android-sdk-macosx` there are those directories:

```
A. drwxr-xr-x   5 dele  staff    160  8 11 11:26 build-tools
B. drwxr-xr-x   3 dele  staff     96  8 11 15:05 cmdline-tools
C. drwxr-xr-x  21 dele  staff    672  8  7 19:37 emulator
D. drwxr-xr-x   3 dele  staff     96  8  7 19:26 licenses
E. drwxr-xr-x   3 dele  staff     96  8  7 19:33 patcher
F. drwxr-xr-x  19 dele  staff    608  8  7 19:26 platform-tools
G. drwxr-xr-x   5 dele  staff    160  8 11 11:02 platforms
```

and I find in `dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml` there have contents:

```
1.Android SDK Platform 
2.Sources for Android
3.NDK (Side by side) 
4.NDK bundle
5.Android SDK Build-Tools
6.​Android SDK Patch Applier 
7.​Android SDK Command-line Tools
8.Layout Inspector image server
9.​CMake
10.Android Auto Desktop Head Unit Emulator
11.​Android Emulator
12.​Android SDK Tools
```

Through I analysis I know:
the 1,5,6,7,11 should below to directory like below.

```
A. build-tools   <-5
B. cmdline-tools <-7
C. emulator      <-11
D. licenses
E. patcher       <-6
F. platform-tools
G. platforms     <-1
```

but how about `2,3,4,8,9,10,12` below to where? whether should I mkdir for them each other?
and what should below to `D` and `F`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you care about how the SDK packages relate to directories under the SDK root? Are you trying to install the SDK without using the SDK manager and/or Android Studio? For any "normal" installation method, you should not need to manually make any directories; they are all created as needed.

Regarding the packages:

- "Sources for Android" (2), when installed, go into a top-level directory called `sources`. Each Android version is in a subdirectory (like `android-30`) under it.
- "NDK (Side by side)" (3) and "NDK bundle" (4) both refer to the same NDK archives. When installed "side by side", each NDK version lives under the top-level directory `ndk`, in a subdirectory named after its version. IIRC, the (older) "bundle" method of installing used to put the NDK directly in an `ndk-bundle` top-level directory, allowing you to install only one version at a time. (The even older method of installing the NDK had you install it as a standalone product, not through the SDK manager.)
- "Layout Inspector image server" (8) is called `skiaparser` in terms of directories.
- "CMake" (9) goes under `cmake/3.18.1` (or whatever the appropriate version is).
- "Android Auto Desktop Head Unit Emulator" (10) is in `extras/google/auto`.
- "Android SDK Tools" (12) lives under a top-level directory called `tools`.

And for the remaining directories you mention:

- `licenses` (D) contains any license files (`android-sdk-license`, `android-sdk-preview-license`, ...) related to by SDK packages you've installed.
- `platform-tools` (F) is the directory for the package "Android SDK Platform-Tools", which you can also find in `repository-2.1.xml`.